# How is Gendry supposed to fulfill Arya's request?

Tags: game-of-thrones

There are no dimensions. How is Gendry supposed to make it? Is it a blowgun? A spear? What materials does it require? Gendry is supervising the forge for thousands of dragonglass weapons and Arya comes to him with this little drawing. Is he a joke to her?

[image: Close up of Arya's schematic she gives to Gendry; an unfurled scrolls shows a crude drawing of a spear tip with an arrow indicating it inserts into a longer handle]

How is he supposed to make what Arya wants from that drawing?

Comment: In all seriousness, master machinists at national labs sometime have to deal with people coming to them with a half-baked idea and a crappy drawing. So much so that they are *happy* to see a grad student who took a drafting class in high school and has actually brought a crappy, hand-sketched, three-sided projection with dimensioning and hidden lines indicated. Not because the sketch is good enough, but because it gives them a good basis to ask the questions that will let them understand what is *really* wanted.

Comment: You stole that from r/freefolk right  https://i.redd.it/yfpkzqcztgs21.png

Comment: “What materials does it require?” — as the diagram clearly indicates, Dragonglass for the tip. Gendry's probably one of the few people in Westeros who knows what the other materials should be for a Dragonglass weapon.

Comment: Related question from sister site [What is Arya's weapon design?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98377/what-is-aryas-weapon-design)

Answer (score 6):

**What is it:** We'll find out soon enough, but it looks like it might be a dart similar to [those used by Byzantine infantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumbata), with some kind of [thrower similar to an atlatl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower), which enables them to be thrown further.

[image: Example ancient dart heads: arrow tips inserted into larger mounts] [image: Diagram showing how the dart launcher would work; a man holds the end of a long stick with the dark on the end; he launches it like a spear but keeps held of the stick sending the dart flying out the end]

It's different to the classic atlatl design, which is used with full-length spears, whereas this looks more suited to throwing smaller projectiles, which would allow someone like Arya to carry more darts and take out more undead. The dart or short spear would sit in the hollow part and the user could use an overarm cricket-bowling motion, flinging the dart forward with more force than would be possible using the arm alone. The small size doesn't sacrifice effectiveness given the effectiveness of even small wounds from dragonglass.

But we're speculating and that's just one possibility. There is some more discussion and other possibilities (such as a spear that splits into two one-handed weapons) under [this Movies & TV question, **"What is Arya's weapon design?"**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98377/what-is-aryas-weapon-design), including some teasing quotes from the show's weapons designer. We'll find out soon.

---

**Why doesn't she provide a complete schematic:** Smiths are skilled tradespeople, not hammer-monkeys who need precise instructions. They're the ones best placed to choose the type of wood, get the weighting and length right, etc etc.

There are few things more annoying for a master craftsman than a client who thinks they know your job better than you do.

Also, keep in mind that most smiths, and most of their clients, are illiterate - it's absolutely normal to ask for something to be made based on an approximate idea and size, where the skilled smith then uses their judgement and experience to work out the details. Sometimes the client may have someone like an architect who is giving precise direction, but for most commissions this won't be the case.

Comment: It's probably more of a longer weapon that can shorten to two smaller ones, see [my answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/98387/45378) to a related question on M&TV.

Comment: The pointy end seems to be on distinct sides for Arya's design and for the darts you mention.